# Parse Server URL after Migration In Swift Xcode 6.4

Tags: swift, xcode, parsing, amazon-web-services, parse-server

I am Facing a problem When migrating my parse TO AWS,

Everything is configured correctly and the DB is working now on AWS,

The problem is with my Swift Code, When I try to change to Application Information
I was Using

Parse.SetApplicationId("AppId","ClientKey")  --> was great

but When I migrated my App I have to enter the Server URL, and I used the ParseClientConfiguration with its parameters, but it always shows an error

as in the picture,

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/afosB.png)

I am Using Parse 1.9 as shown in the PFConstants.h in the framework

When I try to update it it always shows error

can any body help me

Comment: Double check whether OLD PARSE filed are removed from the project.

Comment: I checked that, The strange thing is that, the project build correctly when I Use Xcode 7.2 but When I Use Xcode 6.4 it shows the above error.

Comment: Okay. Please mention this too in question.

Comment: I Edited the Question, Is there any other way to solve this issue, because in xcode 6.4 it show many error with Parse code e.g. PFConstants.h file.

I need to add the server URL ASAP

Comment: I am using Xcode 7.3.1 and I am not facing issue. If I found any solution then I will let you know.

Comment: I found it hard to move all of my code from 6.4 to 7.2, 
I have to change 300 errors. That is why I stuck to 6.4

Comment: if you plan to maintain your app in future, change your app to latest Swift syntax and latest Xcode

Comment: I am working on that, but lot of errors  are shown when converting the code.

Comment: `ParseClientConfiguration` was only introduced in v1.12.0 of the SDK ([release notes](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Parse-SDK-iOS-OSX/releases/tag/1.12.0)) so you will need to upgrade to at least that version of the Parse SDK